# going back to AppDelegate to recreate a uitabbarcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that is based on a tab bar view with a welcome screen (that leads to either signin or sign up process). basically, if you are logged in - you go straight to the tabbar view and if not, you go to the welcome screen, where you can chose to either go to sign in or sign up. assuming that you go to either sign in or sign up, i would like the tab bar view to reappear, however, all the declarations are in the AppDelegate. how can I "go back" and call the tabbatcontroller? is the structure / flow of my classes correct at all?

so to repeat:

1. user signed in -> first view is tab bar view
2. user logged out -> welcome screen view --> sign in / up screen view --> tab bar view

what i am looking for is what do i need to write in this action method that is called once the user clicks on "sign in" in the sign in page:

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {

?????

}
```

for reference, my appDelegate is:

```
  if(user signed in)
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstTab" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondTab" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, secondNavController, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
else
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    SigninTabBarTemplateViewController *landingPage = [[SigninTabBarTemplateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SigninTabBarTemplateViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = (UIViewController *) landingPage;            
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options you can consider.

This can be easily achieved with the use of **delegate**. If you want to close the VC that you presented modally, give it a `delegate` property. The delegate will be sent a message when required, letting it dismiss the VC.  A good way to go with delegate is to write a custom procotol.

For example :

```
// the delegate will conform to this protocol
@protocol SignInVCDelegate

// this method will be called when required
//
-(void)signInCompleted;

@end
```

Now, make the object you want conforms to that protocol, for example the app delegate.

```
// .h
#import "SignInVCDelegate.h"

@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <..., SignInDelegate> {
    ...
    SignInVC *signIn;
    ...
}

-(void)signInCompleted;

@end
```

The implementation looks like this :

```
// .m
...
-(void)signInCompleted {
    ...
    [signIn.view removeFromSuperview];
}

-(BOOL)applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    if(!logged) {
        ...
        [signIn setDelegate:self];
        [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:signIn
                                                 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Now give `signInVC` a delegate property, which will be set before being presented modally, and send the delegate a message when the sign in process is completed.

```
// in .h
@property(retain) id <SignInDelegate>delegate;

// in .m
@synthesize delegate;

-(IBAction)validateSignIn {
    ...
    [delegate signInCompleted];
}
```

You can write any method you want, this example is simplist, and it is useful to give the delegate some informations. In this case for example you could pass a user name, or user id, or what ever you want.

Another simple option is using **notifications**. This option lets any object informed when something happen, as long as it register for it.  Given the same objects as the previous example, the app delegate will register for the notification, while the sign in view controller will post it.

```
// in app delegate .m
-(BOOL)applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(signInCompleted)
            name:@"UserSignedInNotification"
          object:nil];
}

// in SignInVC.m
-(IBAction)validateSignIn {
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"UserSignedInNotification"
                   object:self];
}
```

More informations about delegates and notifications in [Communicating with Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html).

Comment: Thanks Vince, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Hey @Vince - what is setDelegate in your example? Thanks!

Comment: hey @Vince - any idea how to implement your solution if I have another page between AppDelegate and the SignIn? (it's a welcome view controller)? Thanks!!

Comment: @TommyG - I would use a timer for that. Simply first display the view you want and set up a timer that will 1) remove the welcome view 2) set the rootViewController for the window with your tabBarController and present the sign in VC modally.

Comment: here...do you mind if i send you my code? i am so desperate...i did some weird things with instantiating the AppDelegate in both my signin and signup pages so i could call the tabcontroller, but that sounds really wrong, though it works.

Comment: @TommyG - got it ! I'm a bit afraid, just upgraded to 10.7, and currently downloading Xcode. I'll give you feedback by email for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing something like this in the method where you know the user has successfully logged in. (Assuming SignedInTabbarViewController is your TabBarController)

```
   SignedInTabbarViewController *signedInTabbarViewController = [[SignedInTabbarViewController alloc] init];
   id mainDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
   if( [mainDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(setViewController:)]) {
       [mainDelegate setViewController:signedInTabbarViewController];
   }
   UIWindow   *mainWindow = [mainDelegate window];
   [mainWindow addSubview: signedInTabbarViewController.view];
  [signedInTabbarViewController release];
```

Comment: What you just wrote makes me think that I am missing something big time...I dont really have any class that is a TabBarController - everything is declared in the AppDelegate (above) and from AppDelegate I go to the firstTabBar object (which is the view controller for the first tab). So all my classes are: AppDelegate, FirstTabViewController, SecondTabVireController, HomePage (with the signin/signup buttons, signinview and signup view. Do I need a separate class for the TabBarController?

Comment: Easier if you do it this way. But what you are doing in your "user signed in" block will suffice as well.

Comment: what I dont understand is how can I do it in the signInViewController? I dont have any TabBarController object to call to...everything is in the AppDelegate! Please help.....:(

Comment: You shouldn't be putting both the controllers in the AppDelegate. What @Vince is suggesting is the best way to do this. But if you don't want to do it that way I suggest that in you AppDelegate you set up the SignInViewController and when the user signs in you do the set up of your tabbarcontroller, remove the currentcontroller and then add the tabbarcontroller to the AppDelegate.